# Complex Constraints on fields in SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, unique-constraint

I have the following (simplified) structure that allows me to track equipment that has been assigned to a cell. Since equipment can only be in the cell once in the table, I've created a constraint that says that idEquipment and idCell must be unique in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CellEquipment](
    [idEquipment] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idCell] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CellEquipment] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [idEquipment] ASC,
    [idCell] ASC
)
```

This constraint ensures that I never add the same piece of equipment to a cell twice.

So now I've been tasked with keeping history information. I need to be able to pull up a workorder, see its date, and then find what equipment was used on that work order. A solution is to add date information to the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CellEquipment](
    [idEquipment] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idCell] [int] NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateRemoved] [datetime] NULL,
)
```

Now my constraint from above is broken. `idCell/idEquipment` are no longer unique since equipment can be removed and re-added to the cell. Now I have some tricky date issues to contend with. To ensure data integrity the following must be true for changes to the database:

```
idCell/idEquipment are unique (like before)   OR
idCell/idEquipment's new DateAdded doesn't fall between a DateAdded/Removed OR
idCell/idEquipment's new DateRemoved doesn't fall between a DateAdd/Removed or
idCell/idEquipment's doesn't have a record with DateRemoved=NULL
```

The Check constraints don't have the power to pull this off and the unique index constraints can't do it either. BTW a Check Constraint can be created to ensure that `DateAdded < DateRemoved` (along with other NULL/NOT NULL constraint relationships)

Do I need to do enforce these relationships from code, a transaction, a different model?

Perhaps there is a design pattern that I don't know about that can help with storing such historical data?

Comment: You said, "This constraint ensures that I never add the same piece of equipment to a cell twice." But it allows you to add the same piece of equipment to multiple cells. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Unfortunately there are  cases where that is allowed.  For example there is an oven (a very large oven) that serves multiple cells.  Since the oven is 'calibrated' it needs to be tracked.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's unfortunate. I'd just say that's how the business works.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what *equipment* and *cell* mean to you, I could be way off base here.

But it seems to me that the important information is in the question "What equipment was used in work order number ?" Dates don't really give you that information. But this (air code) structure might.

```
create table work_order_equpiment (
  idEquipment integer not null,
  idCell integer not null,
  foreign key (idEquipment, idCell) references CellEquipment (idEquipment, idCell),
  work_order_number integer not null references workorders (work_order_number),
  primary key (idEquipment, idCell, work_order_number)
);
```

That makes it dead simple to get the equipment used on a given work order. To get the equipment used on a given date, join CellEquipment, work_order_equipment, and workorders, and look at the dates in the workorders table.

Comment: I think that adds redundancy to the database, though you probably can't see that with what I've stated.  We currently log each relevant step in production, who (employee), what (work order), how (work step), when (time stamp), where (work cell).  If the cell/equipment table can be date aware I can find the data by only adding 2 dates to each piece of equipment.  If I do what you suggest I will have tens or hundreds of thousands of new entries (many steps * many machines).

Comment: What you suggest does have the benefit of only tracking the current state of a work cell.  My proposed solution tracks the full history of a workcell which is not a requirement (and likely won't be).

Comment: "If the cell/equipment table can be date aware I can find the data by only adding 2 dates to each piece of equipment." I don't think so. I think you'll need to add a row, including those two dates, for every work order. And I don't see any obvious way for the database to say that *this* piece of equipment was used on *that* work order. It can only say *this* piece of equipment was used on *that* date. Not the same thing in most cases, but it might be the same in yours.

Comment: I have a table with WO/date columns.  I have a second table that has cell/date/equipment columns. I can join these two and say what equipment was in the cell at the time the WO when through.  Granted that data is inferred, however having the line tech bar-code every piece of equipment on every work order won't fly will cause many 1000's of transactions.  All that said, my point in my OQ was to maintain data integrity and you have me thinking about structural solutions now.

Comment: Structure is your friend. (Sometimes, it's your *only* friend.)